# Problema al mostrar un carrousel de bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo un problema estético con el carrousel de bootstrap 4 que estoy implementando. Cuando lo abro, me muestra una línea oscura a la derecha del contenedor, el css del carrousel es el que sigue:

```
/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
   margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
   bottom: 3rem;
   z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
   background-color: white;
}
```

**lo que obtengo es mas o menos esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

logré capturar el momento en que se desliza la imagen de una a otra y se ve que entre las imágenes existe esa linea oscura. Quiero removerla y no sé cómo hacerlo. Si alguien me puede dar una mano, se los agradecería muchísimo... GRACIAS !!!

Comment: Se que no es lo mismo, pero si te quita el problema de la raya.. ¿Y si haces utilizas `class="carousel slide carousel-fade"`en el `div` que define el carousel?

Comment: sabes que probé y no andaba pero hice un clear cache (estoy usando laravel) y funciono !!! lo que estoy notando que los botones de desplazamiento a derecha e izquierda no funcionan...

Comment: Ahora volvi a probar y sigue apareciendo esa raya oscura... no se que pasó...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes algo css que sobreescribir tu carousel. Como `background-color` por ejemplo.

Y los botones necesitan `href` igual a `id` de `div` de carousel.
Por ejemplo: `<div id="gallery-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">` y `<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#gallery-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" >`.

Aqui es una [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-blackburn-0h794?file=/index.html) con fondo blanco y botones.